# How to use ngx-select angular 6

Tags: angular6, angular-ngselect

HTML code:

```
<ngx-select [items]="items" [noAutoComplete]="true" [(ngModel)]="itemId" placeholder="No city selected" (focus)="doFocus()"
  (blur)="doBlur()" (open)="doOpen()" (close)="doClose()" (select)="doSelect($event)" (remove)="doRemove($event)" 
  (selectionChanges)="doSelectOptions($event)"></ngx-select>
```

TS code:

```
 public items: string[] = ['Amsterdam', 'Antwerp', 'Athens', 'Barcelona',
    'Berlin', 'Birmingham', 'Bradford', 'Bremen', 'Brussels', 'Bucharest',
    'Budapest', 'Cologne', 'Copenhagen', 'Dortmund', 'Dresden', 'Dublin',
    'Düsseldorf', 'Essen', 'Frankfurt', 'Genoa', 'Glasgow', 'Gothenburg',
    'Hamburg', 'Hannover', 'Helsinki', 'Kraków', 'Leeds', 'Leipzig', 'Lisbon',
    'London', 'Madrid', 'Manchester', 'Marseille', 'Milan', 'Munich', 'Málaga',
    'Naples', 'Palermo', 'Paris', 'Poznań', 'Prague', 'Riga', 'Rome',
    'Rotterdam', 'Seville', 'Sheffield', 'Sofia', 'Stockholm', 'Stuttgart',
    'The Hague', 'Turin', 'Valencia', 'Vienna', 'Vilnius', 'Warsaw', 'Wrocław',
    'Zagreb', 'Zaragoza', 'Łódź'];



public doFocus = () => console.log('SingleDemoComponent.doFocus');

    public doBlur = () => console.log('SingleDemoComponent.doBlur');

    public doOpen = () => console.log('SingleDemoComponent.doOpen');

    public doClose = () => console.log('SingleDemoComponent.doClose');

    public doSelect = (value: any) => console.log('SingleDemoComponent.doSelect', value);

    public doRemove = (value: any) => console.log('SingleDemoComponent.doRemove', value);

    public doSelectOptions = (options: INgxSelectOption[]) => console.log('SingleDemoComponent.doSelectOptions', options);
```

List is not visible even after following all the steps. I changed the CSS of ul list to opacity: 1.... Bydefault it was opacity:0.

Does anyone know what's wrong here?

Link which I have followed here is

Angular ngx-select

Comment: If you feel my answer is useful. Please vote and approve.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code to make the list viewable.

```
<ngx-select  
  [formControl]="selectControl"
  [allowClear]="true" 
  [items]="selectItems" 
  optionValueField="optionId"
  optionTextField="optionTitle" 
  placeholder="Select...">
</ngx-select>
```

I have created the below stackblitz example.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-select-ex-example-formcontrol-wnbhgs